# Qr Code Generator Command, Discord.Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've made the command and everything but idk how to add an error when the user does not add a link/text.
This is what i've made so far.

```
@client.command()
async def qrcodecreator(ctx, link):
    if link == "":
      await ctx.sent("You did not add a link.")
    else:
      embedd = discord.Embed(title="This is the generated qr code.")
      embedd.set_image(url=f"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=450x450&data={link}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedd)
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command qrcodecreator:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/BlissfulThirstyKilobyte/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/BlissfulThirstyKilobyte/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/BlissfulThirstyKilobyte/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/BlissfulThirstyKilobyte/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/home/runner/BlissfulThirstyKilobyte/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: link is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379235/discord-py-how-to-accept-optional-arguments) answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not answer my question.

Comment: Please elaborate? It makes the argument optional, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Why doesn't that work? It seems like you just need a default argument, like `async def qrcodecreator(ctx, link: str = '')`

Answer (score 1):

TheFungusAmongUs solution does work, it should look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def qrcodecreator(ctx, link=None):
    if link == None:
      await ctx.sent("You did not add a link.")
```